# Pass data to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, webforms

Aim: to pass data from my Webform to SQL Server using a stored procedure. I believe the code is correct apart from the line for the connectionstring but am unsure what it should be.

Issue: passing data from a string to SQL Server via a stored procedure.

Specifically the connection string line, highlighted is `ConfigurationManager`. I've based my code on my VB.Net website code but can't crack this last syntax.

Code:

```
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("test").ConnectionString

Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("InsertXML")
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xml", survey.JobId)

        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

`app.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test" 
             connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Error is "ConfigurationManager is not declated" but not of the Visual Studio drop down suggestions fix it.

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: Added notes above. Basically the connection string line is based on websites I've build not webforms and it's not right, but I'm unsure of the right syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the namespace **System.Configuration**.

And need to add the reference to the assembly **System.Configuration.dll**

To add the reference

- right-click on the References tab
- select add reference
- find System.Configuration

On top you must have

```
Imports System.Configuration
```

Comment: I added System.Configuration as "Imports System.Configuration" as it's VB.NET. I'm using Visual Studio to edit so had no tab but went in via "Project", "Add Reference" thanks. Looks good, I'll retest now.

Comment: sorry for that I'm not well familiar with VB

Comment: No worries, close enough and use to using code from C#

Answer (score 3):

I think you have not added the namespace.
If your error is "Name 'ConfigurationManager' is not declared", then add the namespace:-

```
Imports System.Configuration
```

If this does not solve it, add reference to System.configuration

Answer (score 2):

you wrote test but you need to write: Test

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Test").ConnectionString
```

Comment: Fair comment but not the issue sadly.

Answer (score 0):

this may work:

```
 Private conn As SqlConnection
 Private command As SqlCommand



    Public Sub New()
    conn = New SqlConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YOUR_Database_Name").ToString()
    command = New SqlCommand()
    command.Connection = conn
End Sub
```

in the web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="YOUR_Database_Name" connectionString="Data Source=DATABASE_Location;Initial Catalog=###;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Username;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```